# Stop a module initialising on import in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

I'm working on a notification package and am having some trouble on how to new up a function but not simply when it is imported. For example:

I have this as my notification function:

```js
const sendNotification = async (options: SendNotificationTypes) => {
  const handleChannel = {
    slack: async (options: SlackNotificationTypes) => {
      await sendSlack(options);
    },
    email: async (options: EmailNotificationTypes) => {
      await sendEmail(options);
    },
    sms: async (options: SMSNotificationTypes) => {
      await sendSms(options);
    }
  };

  options.channels.forEach(channel => {
    switch (channel) {
      case CHANNEL_SLACK:
        handleChannel.slack(options.slack);
        break;
      case CHANNEL_EMAIL:
        handleChannel.email(options.email);
        break;
      case CHANNEL_SMS:
        handleChannel.sms(options.sms);
        break;
    }
  });
};
```

My slack notifier looks like this:

```js
const slack = new WebClient(tokenGoesHere)

const sendSlack = async (options: SlackNotificationTypes) => {
  try {
    await slack.chat.postMessage({
      channel: options.channel,
      ...(options.message && { text: options.message }),
      ...(options.blocks && { blocks: options.blocks }),
      ...(options.emoji && { icon_emoji: options.emoji }),
      ...(options.attachments && {
        attachments: options.attachments
      })
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Slack notification failed to send: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

So this works fine but the code fails at points if my environment variables aren't in place (since I'm sourcing the slack token from `process.env`).

Instead, I'd like to be able to instantiate the function when I need it and pass in the slack token at that point. Ideally if there's a way to not need a new instance every time I send the notification, I would want to do that.

I'm pretty stuck on this and think I need to perhaps refactor to a class? Any advice welcome!

Comment: Where's the code that uses `process.env`?

Comment: @Bergi - it would be in `const slack = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_TOKEN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just lazily initialise a single instance:

```
let slack = null; // token not yet available

async function sendSlack(options: SlackNotificationTypes) {
    if (!slack) {
        slack = new WebClient(tokenGoesHere) // hopefully available now
    }
    … // rest of the code using `slack` instance
}
```

However, your environment variables should *always* be already in place when the process starts, or at least be filled in by something like `dotenv` before the modules that use them get loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So if I did this, I'd pass the token as a separate parameter (allowing people to either hardcode the token or use an env value) and then this wouldn't create a new instance every time it gets called across different parts of code?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it would get initialised only on the first call to `sendSlack`. But really, using environment variables should also work with the `const` pattern from your question.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. My strong preference is using environment variables but I need to provide an option for just passing the token as a string too.